# See Stack Overflow profile status from meta

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, profile-page

Why can't we see Stack Overflow numbers and stats from meta profile. If I try to open a users profile in meta, I can only see his stats relating to this site and nothing about Stack Overflow. I think it's equally important to be able to view all stats and accounts from any of the stack... sites.

Comment: ... Stockoverflow? If your company's stock is overflowing, feel free to give me some. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the '**accounts**' tab on the right-edge of the user's profile page. You'll see all of the accounts on other Stack Exchange sites (including SO) that the user has associated this account with. Bear in mind that a user can choose to *not*  associate their accounts on different sites together.

If you do this on your own profile page, you'll also see options to associate / disassociate your own accounts.

Comment: Actually, the Meta sub-site for StackOverflow is separate from StackOverflow whereas the Meta sub-sites for other StackExchange sites are linked to their main sites. For example, meta.superuser.com uses the same account as superuser.com, but meta.stackoverflow.com has a different account from stackoverflow.com. Obviously this is because when new sites were spawned, they eventually got their own Metas instead of sharing one, but StackOverflow still has an independent Meta.